# .find() in range between two data attributes?

Tags: jquery

`$(".date-grid").find( $("[data-date=2018-03-15]") )`
This works.

I have a monthly calendar.
Each day is represented `<td class="date-grid" data-date="2018-06-12">`.

I want to be able to select all day/all `date-grid` between `$("[data-date=2018-03-15]")` and `$("[data-date=2018-03-20]")`.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

If attributes `data-date` are present in original html:

```
var cells = $(".date-grid").find("[data-date]").filter(function() {
  // check $(this).data("date") and return true if it is in range
});
```

If `data-date` values are set through `.dataset` or `$().data`:

```
var cells = $(".date-grid").find("td.date-grid").filter(function() {
  // check $(this).data("date") and return true if it is in range
});
```

Comment: @Aviz "This did not work for me." - a little gnome climbed out of the computer and told you so?

Answer (score 0):

My front-end Dev friend recommended this

```
var rangeDays = [];

var range = $(".date-grid[data-date='2018-03-15']")
    .nextUntil(".date-grid[data-date='2018-03-21']");

range.each(function() {
    alert($(this).attr('data-date'));
    rangeDays.push( $(this) )
});

console.log(rangeDays);
```